# Does the SRS-XB01 Speaker have a duel-stack

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I've been having trouble programmatically connecting to or scanning for the SRS-XB01 Bluetooth speaker on Android using Kotlin.  The one exception is when I use BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() when it's in pairing mode but this is unhelpful since I need to detect it when it is paired.  I tried connecting to it with BluetoothDevice.connectGatt().  I tried scanning for it with BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().bluetoothLeScanner and I tried using BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()

Nothing is working but **I know it's possible because I used an app called "Bluetooth Intensity" and it detects it not only when its paired but also connected and gets it's RSSI about every 4 seconds.**

So I was wondering if it has a duel-stack.  I found a spec saying it's communication system is "ver. 4.2".  I'm under the impression that that's a duel-stack but am not sure.  If so, do I have to use connectGatt in a unusual way?

Edit: I've been able to scan for and detect all my other Bluetooth Clasic and Ble devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SRS-XB01 Bluetooth is capable of playing music and works as a speaker for incoming calls. Both of these functionalities are part of Bluetooth Classic, not of Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). The [Help Guide](https://helpguide.sony.net/speaker/srs-xb01/v1/en/contents/TP0001705160.html) for the speaker also says

> Make the BLUETOOTH connection from the BLUETOOTH device.

No special app, which would be required for BLE, is needed. Just use your phones Bluetooth settings to connect to the speaker.

This also explains why you can't find the speaker using a BLE scanner. The RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication) is not only used by BLE but also by Bluetooth Classic and WiFi.

Bluetooth Version 4.2 does not automatically suggest a dual stack, there could be a device using Bluetooth Classic version 5.0 without BLE functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke saying, "I tried using a bleScanner" but corrected it in the question.  I did find a scanner app that detected it.

Comment: Your correct that there is no special app but I can connect to my duel-stack hearing adds with connectGatt() so I know it's possible at least with some duel-stack devices

Comment: It's possible that the audio is Bluetooth Classic and some information interchange is Ble, no?

Comment: If it is a dual stack device and advertises its presence via BLE you can detect and probably connect to it using a BLE scanner app such as 'nRF Connect'. If you cant find it using a BLE scanner it is not using BLE. Of course it could be that only audio and the hands free profile (for calls) are using Bluetooth Classic, but you won't be able to do anything with BLE without a special app. Since there is none from Sony there will be no BLE. Please check if you can find the speaker using nRF Connect

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using nRF Connect.  But I just wanted to reiterate that as far as I can connect to my Ble Hearing aids directly in my own app with connectGatt and read the RSSI with readRemoteRssi() which is Ble.

Comment: Just found this: "... Android allows a Bluetooth device, connected in one app, to be shared across other apps. Seems like an awful security vulnerability, but is expected behavior."  So I guess it's no surprise I'm able to "connect to it directly"

Comment: Maybe your hearing aids have a dual stack, this speaker, as it seems, does not :)

Comment: nRF Connect detected the SRS-B01 but can't read it

Comment: It seems that nRF Connect was just detecting the SRS-B01 doing a bonded device connect

Comment: It seems likely to me at this point that your right that it does not have a duel-stack.